# Provider not finding Provider from StreamProvider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this "Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Wrapper Widget" when trying to run my code. I can't seem to figure out why it is not reading the the provider. I am just trying to receive the value from the Widget.

I have tried wrapping up the StreamProvider inside the MaterialApp. I have also tried using a Builder widget to send the context, but I can't seem to figure out the issue. I get the issue when trying to get "Provider.of(context)

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromDB(FirebaseUser user){
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<User> get user{
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
    .map(_userFromDB);
  }

  Future signInAnon() async {
    try{
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromDB(user);
    } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print(context);
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(user);
    return Authenticate();
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for all of your help!